# Disable showing entries in /boot/loader/entries folder

Tags: fedora, grub2

I just did a fresh install of Fedora 34 on my personal laptop and I noticed that, at boot, in the GRUB2 menu, some entries show up. This entries are the result of `*.conf` files that can be found in the `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf`. Those configuration files are automatically created when a kernel version is installed.

However, I would like to disable showing these entries in the GRUB2 menu and just show the entries generated with `grub2-mkconfig`. Is there an option line that disable those or can I just remove the folder without any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

- You can remove the folder
- You can change the extension of the files in the folder, i.e. `*.bak`
- You can remove or comment this section in `grub.cfg`:

```
    insmod blscfg
    blscfg
```